Solana Playground - Mainnet
Please need your help with below questions.
-How to connect real phantom wallet and live mainnet on Solana playground online IDE?
-Is it possible to connect to verify my contract on Solana playground IDE and the github link of the code shows in the contract?
-How can we let the contract be not upgradable?
Thank you for your help.

If you are building a program you need to deploy, you are better off doing it locally on your machine.
with that out of the way,

To connect your phantom wallet, click on the top right wallet button -> click on the horizontal hamburger hamburger menu and connect to your phantom wallet



To change your endpoint URL to point to mainnbet-beta cluster, click on the bottom left settings icon and update the endpoint URL to a custom mainnnet beta URL

note that the default mainnet beta URL https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com/ doesn't work.


As of writing this, verifying contracts on Solana playground isn't supported.

To make your contract immutable, after building and deploying your program make it unupgradable using


 solana program set-upgrade-authority --final


Hi @Jimii,
Thank you for your answer, really helpful.
Why can't connect to https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com/? Is it only from the playground that can't connect?
On devnet, it is working now, but when connecting to mainnet-beta, the connection fails.
Also, I tried to connect to Alchemy and the connection also failed.
Please can youhelp with it?
With Devnet:
Details of wallet shows right with SOL balance and the contract works.
With Mainnet-beta and other custom RPC URLs:
Got Connection error on the wallet.
Thank you for your help.

Couldn't add an image to show you the error, I have added a new question and below is the link.
Thank you for your help Jimii
https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/17717/solana-playground-mainnet/17742#17742

@Jad it seems you are already familiar with the tooling. Why do you want to use Solana playground for this as opposed to doing it locally?

Thank you so much @Jimii for your help.
